# Fontawesome não carrega corretamete carrega quadrados

Tags: html5, sass, gulp, bower, font-awesome

Após realizada as configurações e instalar o *font-awesome* com o *Bower* e chamá-lo através do meu arquivo *Sass* através de um arquivo de nome **plugin.sass** o mesmo não está funcionado aparecem somente uns quadrados.

Antes da formatação do computador tinha conseguido resolver esse problema chamando mais alguns imports o que após a formatação não funcionou mesmo assim ja alterei o meu arquivo **_variables.scss** mas mesmo assim o problema persiste, inclusive tentei instalar o *fonteawesome-sass*, mas o problema persistiu.

Configurações do import plugin.sass:

```css
@import molecules/_mixins
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fontawesome
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome-sass/fontawesome
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-solid
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-regular
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-brands
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300)
```

O arquivo **_variable.scss** estava assim:

```css
$fa-font-path:"../webfonts  "!default;
```

insira o código aqui

agora assim:

```css
$fa-font-path:                "./bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/webfonts" !default;
```

Atualmente desinstalei o *fontawesome-sass* o codigo está assim:

```css
@import molecules/mixins
@import ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fontawesome
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-solid
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-regular
// @import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-brands
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300)
```

obs.:  com as linhas comentada não aparece nenhum erro, mas também não aparecem os ícones.
ao remover os comentários o navegador apresenta varios erros pra ser mais exato nove

```
@import molecules/mixins
@import ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fontawesome
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-solid
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-regular
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-brands
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300)
```

segue o report dos erros no console do Google Chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-brands-400.woff2
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-regular-400.woff2 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-solid-900.woff 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-brands-400.woff 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-regular-400.woff 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-solid-900.ttf 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-brands-400.ttf 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    fa-regular-400.ttf
```

Estrutura do diretorio onde estão minhas fonts

[image: Estrutura do diretorio onde estão minhas fonts]

Comment: Sei que pode parecer bobo, mas vc já olhou se todos os arquivos .ttf, .woff .woff2 estão na pasta certa? Essa mensagem fala que ele não achou os aquivos das fontes na pasta que vc indicou... Acho que vc não deveria separar cada font em uma pasta. Deveria ser todas as **fa-** dentro da pasta `/scss/fontawesome` e não `/scss/fa-solid` por exemplo... tenta colocando tudo em uma pasta só. E confere se esse caminho edo path está correto "$fa-font-path:" OBS: O *quadrado* aparece pq foi carregada a font default do browser e nela não existe o caracter unicode do Fawesome

Comment: @hugocsl Na verdade esses outros imports foram uma solução paliativa que tinha dado certo no original era sem os imports de fontes separadas, e tinha funcionado após a formatação do pc nem assim e nem do jeito que deveria ser kkk, adicionei no ultimo edit a estrura de onde esta instalado meu font-awesome

Comment: Já tentou usando o CDN só para testar se a fonte vai renderizar na sua maquina?

Comment: @hugocsl sim com cdn funciona normal qria um jeito de funcionar rodando o do bower

Comment: @hugocsl observação ao tirar as linhas das fonts separadas ñ da erro mas ñ funciona

Comment: @hugocsl  mandei e-mail pra *fontawesome* agora estou aguardando a resposta

Comment: @hugocsl mas me ocorreu uma coisa e vou tentar depois

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, vc pode marcar sua própria resposta como resolvida. []'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver o problema alterando corretamente o $fa-font-path anteriormente assim:

```
$fa-font-path:                "./bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/webfonts" !default;
```

agora assim:

```
$fa-font-path:                "../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/webfonts" !default;
```

e quanto aos demais imports realmente eles são necessários e eu entendi o porque, pois na versão do font-awesome 5 por algum motivo o nome dos icones mudaram e eles estão sendo referenciados no fa-solid, fa-brands e fa-regular e se esses imports não forem feitos eles não serão chamados na pagina corretamente então mantive desta forma:

```
@import molecules/mixins
@import ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fontawesome
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-solid
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-regular
@import ../bower_components/fontawesome/web-fonts-with-css/scss/fa-brands
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300)
```

E agora os ícones aparecem sem nenhum tipo de erro no console.

Comment: Se possível marque como resolvido.